# Select distinct values of property with grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I develop an online store, where each product has offers and offers has properties.

I have this table to store connections between offers and theirs properties and their values.
[image]

Now, I'm trying to obtain all properties which are connected with product.
I've tried to do this with this query

```
SELECT `pp`.`product_id`, `pp`.`offer_id` , `pp`.`property_id`, 
group_concat(pp.property_value separator '^$^') `values`, 
group_concat(pp.property_value_number separator '^$^') `number_values`
FROM `app_catalog_product_properties` AS `pp`
WHERE `product_id` = '41'
GROUP BY `pp`.`property_id`
```

But, as you can see on the next screenshot, it duplicates values(because some of them can be the same for two offers)
[image]

So, my question is: how to select only distinct values for each property?

Comment: @GurV look at the second screenshot, property ids are different, but theirs values don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is `group_concat(distinct)`:

```
SELECT `pp`.`product_id`, `pp`.`offer_id` , `pp`.`property_id`, 
        group_concat(distinct pp.property_value separator '^$^') as `values`, 
        group_concat(distinct pp.property_value_number separator '^$^')  as `number_values`
FROM `app_catalog_product_properties` AS `pp`
WHERE `product_id` = '41'
GROUP BY `pp`.`property_id`;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Completely forgot about distinct. May be I need to sleep a little.